# Collapse some categorical variables in tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a large dataset that has several locations.  However, for one of my analyses, two locations "Wells1" and "Wells2", need to be collapsed into a single location "Wells". All other locations should keep their current names.

There are several excellent questions showing how to do this using different basic R functions ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267312/in-r-how-to-collapse-categories-or-recategorize-variables), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410108/cleaning-up-factor-levels-collapsing-multiple-levels-labels)), but I was wondering if anyone knows which tidyverse function would achieve the same goal.

The only thing I've come up with so far is:

```
case_when(recvDeployName %in% c("Wells1", "Wells2") ~ "Wells")
```

However, I get the following error message:
**Error: Case 1 (`.`) must be a two-sided formula, not a list**

I suspect, I need to specify what should be done with the other categories, but I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: `case_when(recvDeployName %in% c("Wells1", "Wells2") ~ "Wells", TRUE ~ recvDeployName)`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case_when` can be written as

```
case_when(recvDeployName %in% c("Wells1", "Wells2") ~ "Wells",
                TRUE ~ recvDeployName)
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but I'm still getting the same error message.  Can this be used with several other functions? Like in here: tagRecvSummary_tree2 <- df.alltags_tree.sub  %>% 
  case_when(recvDeployName %in% c("Wells1", "Wells2") ~ "Wells",
            TRUE ~ recvDeployName) #%>% 
  group_by(mfgID) %>% 
  summarize(Indi=length(unique(mfgID)),
            Locations=length(unique(recvDeployName)))

Comment: @user3220999  What is `df.alltags_tree.sub`?  Is it a `data.frame`, then you can use `case_when` within `mutate` i.e. `df.alltags_tree.sub %>% mutate(recvDeployName = case_when(recvDeployName %in% c("Wells1", "Wells2") ~ "Wells",
                TRUE ~ recvDeployName))`

Comment: Yes, it is a dataframe.  Thanks!  That worked perfectly!